# Unable to print string concatenated with list

Tags: python, string, join

I have a script that scraps a list of IPs from a router. The final output should look like this:

```
if net ~ [
12.5.161.0/24,
12.9.242.0/24,
12.11.215.0/24,
12.17.239.0/24,
.... etc etc
216.248.237.0/24,
216.248.238.0/24,
216.248.239.0/24,
216.251.224.0/19,
216.253.79.0/24
] then {
    accept;
} else {
    reject;
}
```

I've gotten to the point where i can get the list of IPs in the right format, ie

```
12.5.161.0/24,
12.9.242.0/24,
12.11.215.0/24,
12.17.239.0/24,
.... etc etc
216.248.237.0/24,
216.248.238.0/24,
216.248.239.0/24,
216.251.224.0/19,
216.253.79.0/24
```

The prb I run into is stringing together the str at the beginning with all of my IPs as one batch in the middle and the 4 line str at the end.

So far I have:

```
routes = get_bird_routes(args.s)
prefixes = parse_routes(routes, args.p)
dropped = drop_prefixes(prefixes, args.d)
for p in dropped:

  lines = [   "if net ~ [",      str(p),    "] then {",  "    accept;",   "} else {",   "    reject;",       "}\n"  ]
  print "\n".join(lines)
```

but this gives me

```
if net ~ [
199.89.247.0/24
] then {
    accept;
} else {
    reject;
}

if net ~ [
192.149.228.0/24
] then {
    accept;
} else {
    reject;
}

if net ~ [
206.180.165.0/24
] then {
    accept;
} else {
    reject;
}
```

instead of all my IPs together and the str at the beg and at the end only. I tried to see what type(p) was (before i set it to str(p)) and it came back unicode. Looking at the document, I didnt get a clear understanding of what I was doing wrong. Newish to python still, any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be joining `dropped`, not looping over it.

```
dropped_lines = ",\n".join(dropped)
lines = [ "if net ~ [", dropped_lines, "] then {",  "    accept;",   "} else {",   "    reject;",       "}\n"  ]
print "\n".join(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your list to a string with `str()` and `join()`. Then merge the one string into your logic statement(string) with `.format()`.

Viz:

```
dropped_as_strs = map(str, dropped)        # "a", "b", "c"
dropped_str = ',\n'.join(dropped_as_strs)  # "a,\nb,\nc"

logic = "if net ~ [\n{}\n] then {{\n    accept;\n}} ..."

result = logic.format(dropped_str)
```

(Note the need to double '{' and '}' in `str.format()` calls.)

Comment: i tried doing something similar here before but couldnt get it to work,                      `lines = [   "if net ~ [",      str(p),    "] then {",  "    accept;",   "} else {",   "    reject;",       "}\n"  ]
                                                                                                                 print "\n".join(lines)`